# jq : update json content when path is variable

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following dataset in a file :

```
{
   "storageSummary": 6.8624392E13,
   "audit1": {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.99743587,
         "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
      },
   "audit2": {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.9992917,
         "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
      },
   "audit3": {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.99930555,
         "satelliteName": "ap1.storj.io:7777"
      }
}
```

I want to update the content (I'm storing the json into a variable, since I make several updates, then I'll create a new file), but the path of the data to update is variable :

For example, I have :

```
DS_SRC_FILE="test.json"

DS_OBJECT=$(jq -c '' ${DS_SRC_FILE})

ds="audit1"
new_name="toto"

jq --arg ds ${ds} --arg name ${new_name} '.[]|select(.value==$ds)|=(.satellitename = $name)' <<< ${DS_OBJECT}
```

So, of course, this is failing with `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 36`

What's the right way to do that please ?

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/LuminousDisfiguredOperatingsystem#run working correctly after your JSON is fixed to have correct syntax

Comment: Answers don't belong in questions -- since Choroba suggests the same thing I did, you can accept the existing answer posted below. (Note also that edits that make an answer no longer make sense are frowned on; it would thus be better to keep the broken formatting so people reading the first line of choroba's answer understand what it's in reference to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON doesn't use single quotes. Use double quotes instead, or leave the number unquoted.

The command will still fail: starting with `.[]` will throw away the keys of the object and return the values, so you don't have access to the "audit1" anymore.

Also, to change the value, you can use the plain `=` (and without `select`) as the right hand side is not sensitive to context:

```
jq --arg ds "$ds" --arg name "$new_name" '.[$ds]["satelliteName"] = $name' <<< "$DS_OBJECT"
```

Also note that I double quoted the shell variables which should make the command work even if they contained whitespace.